# Dropwizard add filters to log correlation id

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am working on a project based on dropwizard. I want to log correlation id coming in on the http header of a request at a filter and the also log it when it goes out on the response. Any idea how this could be done? I am making a filter:

```
public class CorrelationIdServerFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {


}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

Then registering it in my application class.

How do I capture and log the correlation id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ready to use solutions out there:

https://github.com/dhatim/dropwizard-correlation-id/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dhatim/dropwizard/correlationid/CorrelationIdClientFilter.java

The pattern is quite simple, validate if the `request` has already an `CorrelationId` header, if so add the header to a `ThreadLocal` your `MDC` or something else where it is easy to retrieve the data. If not generate a new one often a `UUID`.

Pass the `CorrelationId` header to all services you call, be aware of thread switches e.g. in case of an async call or when using a circuit breaker like Hystrix.

Add the header to your logging pattern, if you are using a logger that uses an MDC or a similar facility store the `CorrelationId` there beforehand.

Add the header to the response.

Comment: Bit confused. The file you have linked is ClientFilter. Would I instead need the ServletFilter(from the same project)?

I won't be able to use that dependency directly so will need to make a similar custom implementation.

I am on the server side. Many clients would send and request data from me. I will not be concerned with the Correlation ID coming though from the request. 

Would I need to implement the servletFilter class?